# Max Array Length in Julia

Tags: julia

I can create an array of a **million** elements like this:

```
Array(1:1_000_000)
Vector{Int64} with 1000000 elements
```

but if I try to create an array of a **billion** elements I get this:

```
Array(1:1_000_000_000)
Julia has exited.
Press Enter to start a new session.
```

Is Julia not able to handle a billion elements in an array or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: note that for many purposes, you could use `1:1_000_000_000` as a range (which will only store three numbers). In general using efficient datastructures really pays off in Julia

Comment: Well, except for the contraints by available physical memory, there is an inherent limit given by the maximum virtual memory that can be adressed using the word size, and the maximum array length that can be represented by an integer (unless you write an array type that uses `BigInt` internally...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating an Array of `Int64`, each of which needs to be stored in memory:

```
julia> sizeof(3)
8
```

So at some point you're bound to run out of memory - this is not due to some inherent limit on the number of elements in an array, but rather the size of the overall array, which in turn depends on the size of each element. Consider:

```
julia> sizeof(Int8(3))
1

julia> [Int8(1) for _ in 1:1_000_000_000]
1000000000-element Array{Int8,1}:
 1
 1
 1
 ⋮
 1
 1
 1
```

so filling the array with a smaller data type (8-bit rather than 64-bit Integer) allows me to create an array with more elements.

Comment: Hm, does that mean I can create billion element vectors only for `Int8` but not for `Int64`? Wouldn't that be weird?

Comment: Just to add; the actual error is hidden by Juno. If you run the command in a regular Julia REPL you get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: > Hm, does that mean I can create billion element vectors only for Int8 but not for Int64? Wouldn't that be weird? 

Why is that weird? The `Int64` case required 8GB of memory, but the `Int8` case 1GB.

Comment: @fredrikekre really? When I run it in a regular Linux terminal it's just `julia> Array(1:1_000_000_000)
Killed
`

Comment: I get it at least, might be OS dependent though.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm on Manjaro FWIW

Comment: How is it weird that you can make bigger `Int8` arrays than `Int64` arrays? That's like saying it's weird that you can fit 10 bicycles in your garage, but not 10 pickup trucks.

Answer (score 7):

While there is no limit how big an `Array` can be in Julia there is obviously the available RAM memory limit (mentioned in the other answer). Basically, you can assume that all your available system memory can be allocated for a Julia process. `sizeof` is a good way to calculate how much RAM you need.

However, if you actually do big array computing in Julia the above limit can be circumvented in many ways:

1. Use massive memory machines from a major cloud computing provider. I use Julia on AWS Linux and it walks like a charm - you can have a machine up to 4TB RAM on a virtual machine and 24TB RAM on a bare metal machine. While it is not a Julia solution, sometimes it *is* the easiest and cheapest way to go.
2. Sometimes your data is sparse - you do not actually use all of those memory cells. In such cases consider [`SparseArrays`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/). In other cases your sparse data is formatted in some specific way (e.g. non-zero values only on diagonal) in that case use [`BanndedMatrices.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/BandedMatrices.jl). It is worth noting that there is even a Julia package for [infinite algebra](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/InfiniteLinearAlgebra.jl). Basically whatever you find at the [Julia Matrices](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices) project is worth looking at.
3. You can use [memory mapping](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap/) - that means that most of your array is on disk and only some part is hold in RAM. In this way you are limited by your disk space rather than the RAM.
4. You can use [`DistributedArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl) and have a single huge `Array` hosted on several machines.

Hope it will be useful for you or other people trying to do big data algebra in Julia.